# some constants in php will not found

Tags: php, scope, constants

I'va a constant named __Username in this, there are a username for db access.
But, sounds the error message, it cant resolve this constant. What I've does wrong?

**config.php**

```
<?php

define("__Password", "xxx");
define("__Database", "xxx");
define("__Table", "xxx");
define("__Username", "xxx");

?>
```

**db.php**

```
<?php

include('config.php');

function validateUser($username, $password){
    $pswd = '';

    $db_handle = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', __Username, __Password);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db(__Database, $db_handle);

    if($db_found) {
        $query = "select * from users where username = '" . $username . "'";

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $pswd = $db_field['password'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    if($pswd == $password)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
?>
```

Has someone an idea?

Comment: Can your constants start with a double underscore? What happens if you use a single or no underscore?

Comment: when you try to just echo __Username, what do you get? BTW... you should  use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL instead of mysql_ functions.

Comment: Please post the actual error message.

Comment: Also, as @Lupin says: Please [don't use `mysql_*`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1); the `mysql_*` functions are outdated, [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), and insecure. Use [`MySQLi`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Though you can use double underscore for constants, why would someone do that? As the other commenters have stated, please don't use mysql_ as it is to store passwords in plain text

Comment: If I use echo, I'll get the name of the constant, that mean's the constants wount be found, right? But why?